# application of optimal control for spacecraft control on elliptical orbits

Tags: spacecraft

I want to start writting paper for spacecraft control on elliptical orbits, start with introduction of what is orbits and different object out of earth and on orbits(currently and till now) so I want to start main part to know how many method do we have ? which mathematical methods? with which programming language can we do it and so on?
I need you advice like a path way to guide me on that then I will start to search for each line of mentioned pathway!
Thank you in advance

Comment: Your question sounds pretty broad and open-ended, and that doesn't fit well with the format of Stack Exchange. It would be much better if you asked a pretty specific question. Why don't you describe a specific example that is *roughly like* what you are writing about. Mention rough numbers for perigee and apogee, spacecraft size and mass, and what kind of systems in place to measure, and maintain attitude. You'd run a thruster-only system differently than one with reaction wheels unloaded by thrusters, and a four-wheel system differently than a three-wheel system.

Comment: Before starting on any kind of optimal control you need a good understanding of the different forces/perturbations acting on your satellite. Once you know what perturbations you need to take into account you have to look into how to model these forces. I'd use an existing library such as OreKit (JS) or TuDat (C++). Once you have this model, you can start looking into optimal control methods to determine station-keeping manoeuvres.